# IPN stimulator returns error 'IPN Delivery Failed:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR'?

Tags: python, django, paypal, amazon-web-services, django-paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal to my website.

so i downloaded [dcramer django paypal](https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal) from github.
unzipped and pasted the paypal folder in my project directory. i added `INSTALLED_APPS = (... 'paypal.standard.ipn', ...)`  and `RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'suhailvs@gmail.com'` to **settings.py**.

and `(r'^paypal/notify/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),` to my **urls.py**

i hosted it in [amazon aws](http://aws.amazon.com/).

i tried to stimulate ipns at [paypal ipn simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator).

I entered the `IPN handler URL` as `http://<mysite address>/paypal/notify/` and when i clicked the `send ipn` button i got error:

[image: ipn error]

Comment: All I can tell you; we're getting a HTTP 500 back from your IPN listener when we send the IPN POST payload to it. What can you see in your error logs?

Comment: @PayPal_Robert the problem may be due to amazone.aws or something. because i put it in rhcloud server `http://my-picks.rhcloud.com/paypal/notify` and checked with ipn simulator  and it works fine.

Comment: That would be strange, since AWS/RHCloud would affect the infrastructure. Perhaps by moving you've made a change to your environment which resolves this (for example including a required library that wasn't available on your AWS EC2 instance).

Comment: @PayPal_Robert it is working fine in AWS. my site have some typo erros. thanks for your comments

Comment: @PayPal_Robert if you give IPN handler url `http://<url>/paypal/notify` it will return `500: error`. the problem is with '/', ie if you give `http://<url>/paypal/notify/` it will works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved the Problem. Need '/' at the end of IPN Handler URL

if you give IPN handler url

```
http://<url>/paypal/notify
```

it will return `500: error`.

But if you give

```
http://<url>/paypal/notify/
```

it will works fine.